# Why does PyYAML/ruamel combine escaped surrogates on Python 2?

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

For a Python project that specifies some of its testcases in YAML files, I'd like to specify byte strings in UTF-8 encoding in the YAML testcases, including invalid UTF-8 sequences such as unpaired surrogates or swapped high/low surrogates for the purpose of testing the handling of them by the Python project.

I am using double quoted scalars in the testcase YAML (because that is the only way to specify escape sequences in YAML) and 16-bit unicode escapes (e.g. "\u03B5") to specify the surrogate code points.

Our Python project uses PyYAML to load the testcase YAML files, but I verified that the results below also apply to ruamel. The following is an example with PyYAML (on both Python 2.7 and 3.7, unless otherwise stated, and on macOS with CPython):

```
>>> import yaml  # PyYAML

# some valid Unicode character (lower case greek epsilon, fwiw)
>>> yaml.safe_load('x: "\\u03B5"')  
{'x': u'\u03b5'}

# invalid unpaired surrogate
>>> yaml.safe_load('x: "\\uD800"')  
{'x': u'\ud800'}

# invalid swapped high/low surrogates
>>> yaml.safe_load('x: "\\uDC00\\uD800"')
{'x': u'\udc00\ud800'}

# valid surrogates, but using surrogates is illegal in UTF-8
>>> yaml.safe_load('x: "\\uD800\\uDC00"')  
{'x': '\ud800\udc00'}  # on Python 3.7
{'x': u'\U00010000'}   # on Python 2.7  <-- why??
```

The behavior of the last case above on Python 2.7 makes it impossible to pass that case as intended to our Python project, because it gets "corrected" by either PyYAML or Python itself.

Where does this "correction" happen, and can it be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what versions you are using, but I cannot reproduce this. Only `libyaml` seems to
have problems with your input:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
print('Python:     ', sys.version_info[:2])
import yaml as pyyaml
print('PyYAML:     ', pyyaml.__version__)
import ruamel.yaml
print('ruamel.yaml:', ruamel.yaml.version_info)

yaml_str = 'x: "\\uD800\\uDC00"'
print('yaml_str', yaml_str)

print(repr(pyyaml.safe_load(yaml_str)['x']))



for typ, pure in [('rt', True), ('safe', True), ('safe', False)]:
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ=typ, pure=pure)
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
    print(repr(data['x']))
```

gives:

```
Python:      (2, 7)
PyYAML:      5.1.2
ruamel.yaml: (0, 16, 6, u'dev')
yaml_str x: "\uD800\uDC00"
u'\ud800\udc00'
u'\ud800\udc00'
u'\ud800\udc00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ryd-of-anthon/ryd-111/tmp_0.py", line 20, in <module>
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
  File "/home/anthon/.venv/27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 341, in load
    return constructor.get_single_data()
  File "/home/anthon/.venv/27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 111, in get_single_data
    node = self.composer.get_single_node()
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 706, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser.get_single_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 724, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._compose_document
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 775, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 889, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._compose_mapping_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 731, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._compose_node
  File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 904, in _ruamel_yaml.CParser._parse_next_event
ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while parsing a quoted scalar
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 4
found invalid Unicode character escape code
  in "<byte string>", line 1, column 7
```